# Evitar que el usuario ingrese dos símbolos seguidos

Tags: python, email

estoy aprendiendo a programar en python y un ejercicio pide que cree un "verificador de email", quiero saber como puedo hacer para que, cuando un usuario ingrese por input su email, diga "correo incorrecto" si ingresa por ejemplo:("pero..gato_2@aas__asd.com"; "pero--gatoo@asda.org"), y que diga "correo correcto" si ingresa:("perro.gato.22@asdasd.can"; perro_gato_22@fen_can.anm"). Es decir quiero evitar que ingrese dos símbolos seguidos, gracias por su repuesta, les dejo lo que tengo hecho:

```
print("========================================")

print("Verificador de Email")

print()

miEmail=input("Introduce tu dirección de email: ")

verificacion=miEmail.partition("@") # convierte el correo en una tupla de tres elementos, usando como referencia el arroba

parte_local,arroba,dominio=verificacion # se iguala cada elemento de la tupla "verificacion" con una variable

contador=0


caracteres_no=[" ", "\"", "#", "$", "$", "!", "/", "(", ")","=", "?", "¿", "°","%", ":" , "," ,".."]

for i in miEmail:
    if(i=="@" ):

        contador=contador+1

if contador==1  and len(parte_local)<=64 and len(dominio)<=254 and dominio==dominio.lower() : 

    for i in (parte_local+dominio):
        if  i in  caracteres_no:

            print("El email no es correcto")
            break
    else:

        print("El email es correcto")

else:
    print("El email no es correcto")
```

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Lo mejor es que uses una expresión regular. Por cierto, ¿`gatoo` no es válido?

Comment: Las letras se  pueden repetir, los símbolos no.

Answer (score 0):

yo ya llevo un rato programando en python pero se podría decir que siempre estamos aprendiendo.

Lo primero que hice fue crear una lista `simbolos` con los posibles símbolos que el usuario podría ingresar, esta lista a puedes rellenar con todos los símbolos que se te ocurran, yo solo le puse algunos para probar el código.

Después hice una variable llamada `caracter_comparación` en un inicio vacia con el objetivo de guardar cualquier caracter que este en la lista `simbolos` una vez que aparezca.

Posteriormente puse algunos ifs dentro de tu bucle de comparación. El primero de ellos compara si `i` es igual a `caracter_comparacion`, si es asi sale del bicle e imprime "El mail no es correcto", si no resetea la variable y la vacía.

El siguiente if lo único que hace es revisar si `i` es igual a algun simbolo de la lista `simbolos`, si es asi guarda i en `caracter_comparacion` para poder ser comparado en la siguiente vuelta de bucle.

Y es lo único que hice. Lo probe con "pero..gato_2@aas__asd.com" y "perro.gato.22@asdasd.can" y obtuve buenos resultados. Si tienes alguna duda no dudes en decirme. El código quedó asi:

```
print("========================================")

print("Verificador de Email")

print()

miEmail=input("Introduce tu dirección de email: ")

verificacion=miEmail.partition("@") # convierte el correo en una tupla de tres elementos, usando como referencia el arroba

parte_local,arroba,dominio=verificacion # se iguala cada elemento de la tupla "verificacion" con una variable

contador=0


caracteres_no=[" ", "\"", "#", "$", "$", "!", "/", "(", ")","=", "?", "¿", "°","%", ":" , "," ,".."]

simbolos =[".","-","_"] #agrega todos los que necesites

for i in miEmail:
    if(i=="@" ):

        contador=contador+1

caracter_comparacion = ''

if contador==1  and len(parte_local)<=64 and len(dominio)<=254 and dominio==dominio.lower() : 

    for i in (parte_local+dominio):

        if i == caracter_comparacion:
            print("El email no es correcto")
            break
        else:
            caracter_comparacion = ''

        if i in simbolos:
            caracter_comparacion = i
            continue

        if i in caracteres_no:
            print("El email no es correcto")
            break

    else:

        print("El email es correcto")

else:
    print("El email no es correcto")
```

Comment: Gracias morpheus94 , funciona perfecto, ahora necesito comprender porque funciona (esa parte me toca a mi para entender ).